# Why i can't use LPCRITICAL_SECTION and CRITICAL_SECTION

Tags: c++

I'm working on a shared project.
I got some identifier errors, VS C++ 2005 doesn't know CRITICAL_SECTION and LPCRITICAL_SECTION.

```
LPCRITICAL_SECTION GetReadCS() { return &m_ReadCS; }
LPCRITICAL_SECTION GetWriteCS() { return &m_WriteCS; }
```

and

```
CRITICAL_SECTION    m_ReadCS;
CRITICAL_SECTION    m_WriteCS;
```

and got some errors

```
warning C4183: 'GetReadCS': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
warning C4183: 'GetWriteCS': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'm_WriteCS'
```

Why LPCRITICAL_SECTION and CRITICAL_SECTION is undefined? How do I can make C++ know it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you include windows.h?

```
#include <windows.h>
```